# Huawei Matebook D14 - AMD Renoir Radeon High def Audio NOT WORKING

Tags: pulseaudio, speakers, amd-ryzen, output, huawei

I just bought a Huawei Matebook D14 with a Ryzen 5 5500U. Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, and it's really fast and good looking laptop but... I just realize that the Audio doesn't work properly.

I have been reading all day in forums, and haven't found a lot of information about the Audio controller.

First, on the output interface at "Gnome Settings" I get a Dummy Output and no sound at all.  Later I read that the Intel driver worked with this chip, and I saw in `lsmod` that the driver was loaded. so I edited:

```
  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I added at the end:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

After rebooting, nothing happened

Then I read that a reboot wont do it; you have to turn it off, so I did. When the PC was on again the Output changed from Dummy output to HDMI/Display Port out. So I connected a TV on the HDMI, and everything worked fine with video and audio over the HDMI, but still no audio on the headphone jack.  There were also no inputs (mic missing) and no audio at all on the built in speakers.

I read that the latest kernel supported this chip, so I installed the Ubuntu Mainline kernel installer and installed the latest kernel, 5.18.8 ... and everything stayed the same.

Here is some info I have from the PC:

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`sudo lspci`:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
```

`inxi -SMA`:

```
    System:
  Host: laptop Kernel: 5.18.8-051808-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.2 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HUAWEI product: NBM-WXX9 v: M1010
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HUAWEI model: NBM-WXX9-PCB-B2 v: M1010 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: HUAWEI v: 2.03 date: 09/06/2021
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.18.8-051808-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

`hwinfo --sound`:

```
18: PCI 300.1: 0403 Audio device                                
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: kEn8.tX5qgIchlH6
  Parent ID: JZZT.uOiGoVFuLy6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:03:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "ATI Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x1637 
  SubVendor: pci 0x152d "QUANTA Computer Inc"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1368 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xd03c0000-0xd03c3fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 58 (101 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00001637sv0000152Dsd00001368bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #20 (PCI bridge)
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux laptop 5.18.8-051808-generic #202206290850 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 29 08:59:08 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
tls                   110592  0
st                     65536  0
nvram                  16384  0
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  9
cmac                   16384  2
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
amdgpu              10485760  19
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
bnep                   28672  2
snd_acp3x_rn           16384  0
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
rtw88_8822ce           16384  0
snd_sof_amd_renoir     16384  0
joydev                 32768  0
iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu
rtw88_8822c           503808  1 rtw88_8822ce
snd_sof_amd_acp        36864  1 snd_sof_amd_renoir
gpu_sched              45056  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 amdgpu
snd_sof_pci            24576  1 snd_sof_amd_renoir
rtw88_pci              32768  1 rtw88_8822ce
btusb                  61440  0
snd_sof               184320  3 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
kvm_amd               155648  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  0
rtw88_core            286720  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8822c
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1
ttm                    81920  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
kvm                  1060864  1 kvm_amd
uvcvideo              110592  0
btintel                40960  1 btusb
drm_dp_helper         151552  1 amdgpu
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
mac80211             1265664  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
cec                    77824  1 drm_dp_helper
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_acp_pci            16384  0
bluetooth             790528  34 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_soc_es8316         49152  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  1 snd_hda_intel
input_leds             16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
aesni_intel           376832  9
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
snd_soc_core          344064  5 snd_acp3x_rn,snd_sof,snd_soc_es8316,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
rc_core                65536  1 cec
snd_hda_codec         159744  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pci_acp6x          16384  0
videodev              253952  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
drm_kms_helper        188416  4 drm_dp_helper,amdgpu
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
huawei_wmi             20480  0
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_core          110592  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,huawei_wmi,snd_sof
snd_pci_acp5x          20480  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
rapl                   20480  0
cfg80211              987136  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
sparse_keymap          16384  1 huawei_wmi
serio_raw              20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_multitouch         32768  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
snd_acp_config         16384  3 snd_rn_pci_acp3x,snd_acp_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_pcm               147456  13 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_soc_es8316,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pcm_dmaengine
sysimgblt              20480  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_acp_config,snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
ccp                   102400  1 kvm_amd
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
k10temp                16384  0
snd                   106496  15 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
amd_pmc                24576  0
sch_fq_codel           24576  1
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       122880  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
drm                   593920  14 gpu_sched,drm_dp_helper,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm
parport                69632  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
nvme                   49152  2
hid_generic            16384  0
xhci_pci               24576  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme_core             135168  3 nvme
i2c_piix4              28672  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  2 huawei_wmi,wmi_bmof
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
i2c_hid                32768  1 i2c_hid_acpi
video                  53248  0
hid                   151552  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
```